# String comparison not working using php

Tags: php, encryption, string-comparison, blowfish, crypt

Source of all of the follwoing lines : http://www.the-art-of-web.com/php/blowfish-crypt/

I use this method to check if my server accepts blowfish crypting :

```
if(defined("CRYPT_BLOWFISH") && CRYPT_BLOWFISH) echo "CRYPT_BLOWFISH is enabled!<br>";
```

And that's ok :

> CRYPT_BLOWFISH is enabled!

I use this method to build a blowfish salt

```
function getBlowFishSalt() { 
    $salt = ""; 
    $salt_chars = array_merge(range('A','Z'), range('a','z'), range(0,9)); 
    for($i=0; $i < 22; $i++) { 
        $salt .= $salt_chars[array_rand($salt_chars)]; 
    }

    return ($salt);
}
```

And that's ok . I uses the following

> ZTbCMA3q8QY3A9a6E13JSn

I use the following method to crypt password :

```
function crypt_blowfish($input, $salt, $rounds = 12) { 
    return crypt($input, sprintf('$2a$%02d$', $rounds) . $salt); 
}
```

using these steps :

```
$salt = "ZTbCMA3q8QY3A9a6E13JSn";

$password = "just_a_password";
print($password . " crypted as : <input type='text' size='80' value='" . crypt_blowfish($password, $salt) . "'><br>");
```

I get the following hashed password :

> $2a$12$ZTbCMA3q8QY3A9a6E13JSe7pxGA6JsO.ksFGGeayxWXhcJalJ5ytm

Then I try to compare things :

```
$hashedPassword = "$2a$12$ZTbCMA3q8QY3A9a6E13JSe7pxGA6JsO.ksFGGeayxWXhcJalJ5ytm";

if (crypt_blowfish("just_a_password", $salt) == $hashedPassword)
    print ("just_a_password" . "recognized<br>");
else 
    print ("just_a_password" . " ---------- " . crypt_blowfish("just_a_password", $salt) . " ------------- " ." ko<br>");

if (crypt_blowfish("just_a_password", $salt) === $hashedPassword)
    print ("just_a_password" . "recognized<br>");
else 
    print ("just_a_password" . " ---------- " . crypt_blowfish("just_a_password", $salt) . " ------------- " ." ko<br>");

if (strcmp(crypt_blowfish("just_a_password", $salt), $hashedPassword) == 0)
    print ("just_a_password" . "recognized<br>");
else 
    print ("just_a_password" . " ---------- " . crypt_blowfish("just_a_password", $salt) . " ------------- " ." ko<br>");
```

But none of these returns me a OK result.
On screen and into the HTML code, the strings are exactly the same, so I don't understand why the php code do not recognize these as the same.

Can you help me ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Oliver,

I think I figured out your problem, when you use double quotes, php interprets strings with $ as being variables.  If you change

```
$hashedPassword = "$2a$12$ZTbCMA3q8QY3A9a6E13JSe7pxGA6JsO.ksFGGeayxWXhcJalJ5ytm";
print($hashedPassword);
```

to:

```
$hashedPassword = '$2a$12$ZTbCMA3q8QY3A9a6E13JSe7pxGA6JsO.ksFGGeayxWXhcJalJ5ytm';
print($hashedPassword);
```

your code should start working.

You can see the difference with the print statements.

Comment: You're a winner :-)  Thank you, I had missed that.